# How to allow CORS in JavaEE Servlets using Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, cors, http-headers

I've already installed the Access Control plugin and It didn't help, and I'm using `servlets` with `gson`, my http methods work if I use an API platform (hoppscotch), my method `GET` is working with `axios` but when I try to send a `POST` from my `vue.js` project using `axios` I get the following `CORS` error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/demo5_war_exploded/client' 
from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

A also this one:

```
xhr.js:233
POST http://localhost:8080/demo5_war_exploded/client net::ERR_FAILED
```

Here is my Java code and I'm using the `headers`, with my `doGet` is working but not with my `doPost`.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(request.getReader());
    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonReader.readObject();
    jsonReader.close();

    // extract the fields from the JSON object
    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
    String email = jsonObject.getString("email");

    // create the Client object
    Client client = new Client(name, email);

    // insert the client into the database
    try {
        clientDao.insert(client);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

This in my `doGet`, which is working.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    String idString = request.getParameter("id");
    if (idString != null) {
        // get the client with the specified id
        int id = Integer.parseInt(idString);
        try {
            Client client = clientDao.buscarPorId(id);
            if (client != null) {
                JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
                builder.add("name", client.getName());
                builder.add("email", client.getEmail());
                JsonObject jsonObject = builder.build();
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.print(jsonObject);
                out.flush();
            } else {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    } else {
        // get all the client
        try {
            // a different way to get the json and simpler TBH
            List<Client> client = clientDao.list();

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String clientJSON = gson.toJson(client);

            PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            printWriter.write(clientJSON);
            printWriter.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8081");` or `resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");`

Comment: @life888888 It worked for my `GET` that is already working but no for my `POST`.

Comment: doGet and doPost are servlet "RECEIVER" methods , if you are trying to use a response of a servlet to make a request to an external machine then use java.net.UrlConnection and java.net.HttpUrlConnection or WSDL web Services connection. XMLHttpRequest as I remember it is .js code for stateful javaScript client side request AJAX

Comment: Note, CORS headers must be correct for their intent. Cross origin request for content is similar if not the same as "portals" and is extremely restricted for security reasons of both content ownership and attacks similar to cookie parameter site origin declaration security.

Comment: Note: XMLHttpRequest can be set as a POST,  it appears you need to set this with Access-Control-Allow-Origin on the AJAX connection. That may not be possible without a proper external site to call just as with registered TLS certificates. Anyhow, the should be in a client page (is it part of the JSON) , but the way you seem to be doing that is what "portal" coding API and framework is for.

Comment: Preflight requests use the `OPTIONS` method. Your server doesn't handle them correctly and CORS preflight fails.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant Thanks for giving me that perspective, it helps me to find the answer now it's working!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the application server, in this case [Tomcat 10](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/filter.html), **but it looks like that is the same for a lot of versions of Tomcat.**

First, you need to create where ever you want inside your `Source root` your `CorsFilter` class implementing `Filter`, in my case the path is `projectName/src/main/java/servlet/CorsFilter.java`, code of the file (you can copy it, just be careful to change the `package` name and to import the servlet with `java` instead of `jakarta` if you aren't using it) is:

```
package servlet;

import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // No initialization required
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // No cleanup required
    }
}
```

The second step is to go inside your `web.xml` file which is inside tomcat, in my case the path is `~/Documents/apache-tomcat-10.1.5/conf/web.xml`, you open the file and add the following code in `web.xml` next to where `<filter>` is commented inside the file, just edit the path of your `CorsFilter.java` in my case is `servlet.CorsFilter`, because you need to add the path from the `Source root`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>servlet.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And the last step is to stop running your project and re-run it.

In addition I'll leave this image as a visual reference:

[image]